# how to access Wordpress session in another function

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables, php-5.3

I am facing problem   to access the session value 
in word press

i am successfully   Set Session Value in   Word press values  using

```
    function register_session(){
        if( !session_id() )
            session_start();
    }
   public function getAll($data) {
       $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ); 
        require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
        add_action('init','register_session');

    $_SESSION['currentPdfDownload']="12";
    $owners['max_download_limit']="20";
}
```

But when i try to access the Session value in other function it return **NULL**

```
 public function new_function(){

       $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ); 
        require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

         if ( is_user_logged_in() )
         {
              echo $_SESSION['currentPdfDownload'];
               echo $_SESSION['max_download_limit'];

}
}
```

Please highlight my mistake 
Thanks in advance

Comment: run register_session in your new_function?

Comment: also, your action for init, is wrapped in another function?

Comment: @Stender  like this
public function new_function(){
        add_action('init','register_session');
 -----------------------------------------------}

Comment: @Stender sure i will share my feedback in next few min thanks Again

Comment: there shouldn't be any reason to have the action in your functions - you should just be able to run it like register_session();

Comment: the action, is for when you want the function to run automatically, but here you want to call the function - Init runs every time the page loads and start to build - meaning wordpress is initialised.